# Testing REST web service client when the services don't yet exist

Tags: javascript, rest

I have already read the posts [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203495/testing-rest-webservices) and [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303911/rest-tools-support-for-development-and-testing) but these are covering the use case of building a REST service on the server and requiring a rapid client in order to test those services.

We have the opposite problem, we are building a web client that will communicate to the server via REST, but the decision has been taken to let the client drive the format of the services on the server, this means the client is being implemented first and the services on the server second.

I am trying to look for a tool which would allow me to very quickly knock up REST web services, which the client could then be tested against. Effectively mocking the server.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your REST service will actually return the data. You should be able to   abstract all the service calls and then mock JSON responses - randomly rotating the responses should be pretty straight forward.

The other thing you could do is put several result docs on the server (as above) and rotate them from the client by randomly altering the requested service URLs.

Comment: Mocking the service call methods and returning JSON is my current approach. This works quite well. I think I'm looking for something that doesn't exist :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a multiplatform proxy written in Java that proxies browsers or whatever network clients you have.

You can assign URLs to files, or even directories, if you want, or you can record sessions to disk and play them later — we use it all the time for mocking up incomplete or inaccessible (e.g., heavily firewalled) servers.

And it is a very good tool for debugging too because it allows to inspect all details of HTTP.

PS: Not affiliated with them, just a happy user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Microsoft world then I would take a look at the Microsoft.Http libraries that are in the WCF REST starter kit.  There is a Microsoft.Http.Test project that has a lot of examples of how to stub http requests by either adding a stub stage in the HttpClient processing pipeline, or by building a dummy server on top of HttpListener.

HttpListener is a great .Net framework class that allows you to build a running web server in just a few lines of code.  Along with the Microsoft.Http library you could produce a server that returns fake results pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery.fixture plugin that is a part of JavascriptMVC framework, but can be used also as standalone component. It provides a very strong approach for mocking the REST services that are not yet implemented by intercepting the ajax requests.

To learn more about it, please visit: http://www.javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.fixture

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a result document and put it on a web server..
Then point the REST URL at the document.
No matter what your input the output is always the pre-formated result.

Comment: Could do but that would only be useful for testing 200 -OK responses. I would love to have something where it could throw me some curve balls in terms of the responses in order to put the client through its paces.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Facade design pattern then simply add a configuration value for a "simulation mode".  You can then create the entire client with a simulation mode.  Then, when the server is ready, update the Facade to work with the new server.

I've done this with several projects and it has been tremendously successful.  Especially in large enterprise applications where some small service could go down, but the rest of the system should continue running.  Just have the facade give a "simulate mode" warning to the user so they know the results probably aren't real.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - use SoapUI from Eviware (free) to Mock your service.

It has the built in concept of a 'Mock' service where you can define an endpoint and have that enpoint respond to requests with realistic looking data. Once defined the mock service can be started and will happily sit there responding to requests from clients. You can even control it programatically and have it send back different responses depending on the request.

The online tutorial on service mocking is really good [here](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html).

It's easier if your application has a WADL or WSDL to work from, but not having these just means that you'll have to put in a little extra effort to create your initial Mock service.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this same question. I have yet to find a descent tool out there to do this. I was really hoping SoapUI would pull through, but after using it extensively I have found their REST support, especially when it comes to Mock REST services, quite lacking.

The best that I could think of would be to build a simple webserver and use filters to send the user to different resources depending on the url. This is fine and dandy for static responses, but what if I want the call to error out or display a little bit different response data. I want something like what SoapUI does with mock SOAP services, where you can run a script that looks at the data and dependent on the data, uses a different SOAP response. Anybody know of such a tool? More support for REST is slated in SoapUI's road map, but I'm guessing not in the near future.