# REST listening tool for testing

Tags: rest, testing

There are lots of tools for testing REST from the client's perspective, as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303911/rest-tools-support-for-development-and-testing).
I am looking for a tool that will *receive* a RESTful network request, and provide some feedback about the headers, request payload, and anything else I should know about. This is to help in building a server side API that receives the REST requests, and validate that messages are being received as expected.

Are there tools available for this?

Comment: You can have [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) generate a response but I guess that can become a mess quickly...

Comment: that looks like the kind of tool i'm looking for. pls add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) generate a response but I guess that can become a mess quickly

You will be looking for the [AutoResponder](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/ComposeAutoresponder) feature together with the [Import and Export](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/ImportExportAutoresponder)

If the url's you need to test is large you can have a set of response files per url to keep things manageable. Those files go with your testset in a sourcecontrol system.