# tool to easily mock restful service

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, testing

Is there a tool to easily mock restful service so that we could test our `Ajax` calls easily?

For example, I need to mock a restful service to return `string` in `JSON` or `XML` format.

Comment: a possbile duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203495/testing-rest-webservices/12298362#12298362

Comment: have you tried an online mocking tools like https://quickmocker.com ?

Comment: You can try https://themockapis.in/ to mock apis and make csv database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might give jasmine-Ajax a shot. https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax

Of course it means you need to test with Jasmine. https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/

Sinon is a very powerful mocking library as well. http://sinonjs.org/ and you can choose your test framework. I have used it with Mocha. http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/

Answer (score 2):

Try [jmockit](http://jmockit.github.io/) ; i had used it for mocking a web service. But this is a Java solution. If you want to mock REST API at server side then this will fit. This will not help if you don't own REST application.

***If you want to mock at client side(in JS) itself;***

You can write your own mocking framework/interface. 
So when you send a request put a layer in-between which can just return you test response instead of actually calling the REST URL.

**Client ---> Mocking Interface---> REST API CALL**

```
function mockingInterface(var url){
    //if original
    //make REST call

    //else; return mocked data
}
```

Comment: What if I don't own REST application? The second way is the only solution?

Comment: Yeah, then better do at client side in JS.

Comment: Thanks. Why cannot I @ you, rai.skumar?

Answer (score 2):

[FakeRest](https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest) does exactly what you want.

```
// initialize fake REST server and data
var restServer = new FakeRest.Server();
restServer.init({
    'authors': [
        { id: 0, first_name: 'Leo', last_name: 'Tolstoi' },
        { id: 1, first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Austen' }
    ],
    'books': [
        { id: 0, author_id: 0, title: 'Anna Karenina' },
        { id: 1, author_id: 0, title: 'War and Peace' },
        { id: 2, author_id: 1, title: 'Pride and Prejudice' },
        { id: 3, author_id: 1, title: 'Sense and Sensibility' }
    ]
});
// use sinon.js to monkey-patch XmlHttpRequest
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith(restServer.getHandler());

// Now query the fake REST server
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/authors", false);
req.send(null);
console.log(req.responseText);
// [
//    {"id":0,"first_name":"Leo","last_name":"Tolstoi"},
//    {"id":1,"first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Austen"}
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://apiary.io/ too.

There you can define the request responses in text format, so in JSON for example. Advantage is that the MOCK API is public so any part of the team can use it.